# How to hide block of code

Tags: latex, literate-programming

I'm writing a program in a .lhs file which contains code in Haskell (I'm specifying this because I want it to be clear that it's not only for rendering a pdf but it's also for being execute with runhaskell or ghci). I'm rendering the code with lstlisting like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}

> Haskell code here

\end{lstlisting}
```

Anyway, the code itself require some modules that I have to import, but I don't want the imports to appear in the resulting pdf. So, I've tried to put the code without the `lstlisting` block, like this:

```
> import X
> import Y
...
```

But it's not working and the resulting PDF renders those lines only not as code like `lstlisting` would do. What should I do to write the import code only for being execute but not to be showed in the PDF itself?

Comment: LaTeX-comment the imports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming) suggests defining a LaTeX macro like:

```
\long\def\ignore#1{}
```

You could also define this with `\newcommand` which, to me, seems more natural:

```
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
```

In both cases, it is used like this:

```
\ignore{

> import Foo.Bar (baz)

}
```

`